# Getting JSDoc output in JSON format

Tags: javascript, json, jsdoc

Is there any way to configure JSDoc such that the output is in JSON format instead of the usual HMTL format?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an option "-X" ("explain") which creates a JSON file with parsed AST.

```
jsdoc -X ./mylib/ > jsdoc-ast.json
```

To understand this JSON you can use documented schema: https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/blob/master/packages/jsdoc/lib/jsdoc/schema.js

Comment: This is the solution I ended up using a month or so back.
Thanks for the well written answer!

Comment: Hey, I am quite new to JSDoc. What is "./mylib/" here?

Comment: @RahulAgrawal just any folder with code you want to document