# JSDoc output as JSON for spa integration

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, jsdoc

I'm currently building a webshop with node.js and I wanted to include a documentation of pretty much all of my commented javascript code. I can easilly create a documentation with JSDoc and create a pretty html documentation, but that's not what I want to have.

I want to create a navigation in my website where the documentation is integrated in my spa. So I have done some research and found some npm modules like [jsdoc-x](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdoc-x) which creates JSON based of the JSDoc comments, but it is rather cryptic and hard to create a proper documentation. Using jsdoc -X ./path/to/js/files > name.json creates a JSON representation of the commented code as well, but again very cryptic and not very practical.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
 /**
  * This is a function.
  *
  * @param {string} bar A parameter
  * @returns {string} A string
  */
  function foo(bar) {
      // do something...
      return bar;
  }

  /**
   * This is another function.
   *
   * @param {string} foo A parameter
   */
   function bar(foo) {
       // do something...
   }
```

should create something like this:

```
  {
     "documentation": [
         {
             "function-name": "foo(bar)"
             "description": "This is a function.",
             "params": [
                 {
                    "param": "bar",
                    "description": "A parameter",
                    "type": "string"
                 }
             ],
             "returns": {
                 "description": "A string",
                 "type": "string"
             }
         }, 
         {
             "function-name": "bar(foo)"
             "description": "This is another function.",
             "params": [
                {
                   "param": "foo",
                   "description": "A parameter",
                   "type": "string"
                }
             ]
         }
     ]
  }
```

Like this I could create a link called "documentaion" which lists all function and their documentations ***inside my spa***.

Comment: Doesn’t jsdoc already have ways of generating documentation websites?

Comment: http://usejsdoc.org/about-getting-started.html#generating-a-website

Comment: @BenSteward Yes, JSDoc is practically all about generating documentaion websites. Which is what I do **not** want. JSDoc generates html, but I need JSON to integrate it into my own spa and not create an extra html site.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25210156/7872063

Comment: @BenSteward I have seen that thread and I tried that `jsdoc -X ./mylib/ > jsdoc-ast.json` as I already mentioned in my start post `jsdoc -X ./path/to/js/files > name.json` It indeed creates a json file, but with humongous amount of meta data which is dificult up to impossible to sort out.

Comment: But if the information you need is there, then that is what you should be using. A few array methods and object accessors and you’re good to go.